# Sair do laço quando a string for vazia ou quando digitar uma palavra específica

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um algoritmo que exiba o preço total das compras. Entro com o produto, preco unitário e a quantidade. Novamente tenho a possibilidade de entrar com o produto e assim sucessivamente. Quando quiser exibir o total, basta teclar enter quando pedir o produto. Ou seja, estou analisando duas possibilidades: 1. Quando a string for vazia ou 2. Quando digitar = e teclar enter. As duas formas não funcionam. Vejamos o código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compras {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nomeProduto;
        float precoUnitario = 0;
        int quantidadeProduto = 0;

        float precoTotal = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Informe o produto");
            nomeProduto = entrada.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Informe o preço do " + nomeProduto);
            precoUnitario = entrada.nextFloat();

            System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de " + nomeProduto);
            quantidadeProduto = entrada.nextInt();

//limpar buffer do teclado//

            entrada.nextLine();

//multiplica quantidade com preço unitário e soma ao total.
        precoTotal = +(precoUnitario * quantidadeProduto);
}

//pede os dados enquanto não digitar "="//

        while (!nomeProduto.equals("="));

//ou se a string for ""

        while (!nomeProduto.isEmpty());


//ao finalizar, mostra o valor total

        System.out.println("O preço total é $" + precoTotal);

    }

}
```

Não sei se as variáveis:

```
String nomeProduto;
float precoUnitario = 0;
int quantidadeProduto = 0;
```

devem ser declaradas dentro do laço, apesar que já tentei e deu erro. Acho que cada vez que entrar no laço, estas três variáveis devem ser reiniciadas. Talvez seja isso que nunca saia do laço.

Comment: Não costumo usar linha de comando, mas pelo que estou vendo a variável precoTotal está sendo iniciada com zero a cada entrada. Ela não deveria estar dentro do lado "do" para que seja acumulada a cada nova entrada?

Comment: @Marcelo Gomes é verdade. Da forma que estou fazendo só calcula o preço total do último produto. Valeu pela observação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, cada `do` deve ter somente um `while` e não dois igual está no seu código. Para consertar isso você poderia por exemplo fazer as duas verificações dentro de um `while` só usando um operador condicional. Exemplo:

```
while (!nomeProduto.equals("=") && !nomeProduto.isEmpty());
```

Para o seu caso vai consertar o erro de sintaxe mas não o de lógica, pois o `precoTotal` poderá receber mais um valor de um produto que não é válido. Essa verificação deixaria o código menos propenso a erro se fosse feita logo após a entrada do nome pelo usuário, colocando ali um `break` caso o usuário entre com uma das condições de saída, fazendo com que a repetição se mantenha enquanto essa condição não for satisfeita.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compras {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nomeProduto;
        float precoUnitario = 0;
        int quantidadeProduto = 0;

        float precoTotal = 0;

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Informe o produto");
            nomeProduto = entrada.nextLine();
            if(nomeProduto.equals("=") || nomeProduto.equals("")) break;

            System.out.println("Informe o preço do " + nomeProduto);
            precoUnitario = entrada.nextFloat();

            System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de " + nomeProduto);
            quantidadeProduto = entrada.nextInt();

            //limpar buffer do teclado
            entrada.nextLine();

            //multiplica quantidade com preço unitário e soma ao total.
            precoTotal = +(precoUnitario * quantidadeProduto);          
        }

        //ao finalizar, mostra o valor total
        System.out.println("O preço total é $" + precoTotal);

    }

}
```

Comment: o while (true) { } significa que é um loop sem condição? Porque aprendemos que as repetições seguem uma condição. Aqui segue a condição do if, mas a linha while (true) sempre será verdade, já que não tem condição de false.

Comment: Ele fica em loop _eterno_, ou seja, essa repetição por si só não tem uma condição de saída, ela é criada artificialmente com uso do `if` e do `break`.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para complementar a resposta do @Math.

Basicamente o seu erro é de lógica. Você está verificando a cada volta (*loop*) se a variável `nomeProduto` está vazia ou tem o valor `=`, quando na verdade, você tem que verificar isso sempre que o usuário inserir o valor no *console*.

Também tem um problema no cálculo de `precoTotal`, ele tem que ser incrementado a cada *loop*, da forma atual ele só está sendo incrementado no final e não somará o preço de todas as entradas digitadas.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    String nomeProduto;
    float precoUnitario = 0;
    int quantidadeProduto = 0;

    float precoTotal = 0;

    while(true) //Loop infinito, será quebrado quando nomeProduto for vazio ou "="
    {
        System.out.println("Informe o produto");
        nomeProduto = entrada.nextLine();

        if(nomeProduto.equals("=") || nomeProduto.isEmpty()) //Verifica logo após a inserção do valor
            break;

        System.out.println("Informe o preco do " + nomeProduto);
        precoUnitario = entrada.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de " + nomeProduto);
        quantidadeProduto = entrada.nextInt();

        precoTotal += (precoUnitario * quantidadeProduto); //Incrementar o valor total a cada loop

        entrada.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("O preco total e $" + precoTotal);
}
```